# Faces invisible from one side using Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have an OBJ file with JPG texture loaded into a page - from one side the faces are visible, but from the other they are invisible.

[image]

Faces visible (a little dark - sorry!)

[image]

Other side - faces not visible.

I tried adding `model.doubleSided = true;` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the double sided flag on the material. Assuming you have something like:

```
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({ color: 0xFF00FF });
```

add:

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

or when you create the material do:

```
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({ color: 0xFF00FF, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
```

EDIT: For the OBJMTL loader that returns an Object3D we would then need to traverse the object to set the appropriate flag:

```
if (object instanceof THREE.Object3D)
{
    object.traverse (function (mesh)
    {
        if (! (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh)) return;

        mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    });
}
```

Comment: The material is loaded as part of an OBJ file, so I don't think I can change the material's sided-ness.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely solves some of the models' problems, but for some reason not all... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceNone );`

Comment: No luck, unfortunately!