# Can't understand why my THREE.js object is partly transparent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a solid (not transparent) object in blender and exported it with three.js blender plugin to get json data.

And now when I'm adding it to three.js there are transparent areas of the object and I can't understand why cause I need it fully solid.

Will appreciate any help with this.

*Here is javascript code:*

```
window.kristal_json =
  "metadata" :
    "formatVersion" : 3.1
    "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.7 Exporter"
    "vertices"      : 12
    "faces"         : 30
    "normals"       : 12
    "colors"        : 0
    "uvs"           : [10]
    "materials"     : 1
    "morphTargets"  : 0
    "bones"         : 0
  "scale" : 1.000000
  "materials" : [
    "DbgColor" : 15658734
    "DbgIndex" : 0
    "DbgName" : "Mat"
    "blending" : "NormalBlending"
    "colorAmbient" : [0.1694117690535153, 0.3545098119156034, 0.6400000190734865]
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.1694117690535153, 0.3545098119156034, 0.6400000190734865]
    "colorEmissive" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    "depthTest" : true
    "depthWrite" : true
    "shading" : "Lambert"
    "specularCoef" : 255
    "transparency" : 1.0
    "transparent" : false
    "vertexColors" : false
  ]
  "vertices" : [-1.0049,-0.55688,0.0199999,-0.904313,0.307844,0.02,-0.147116,-0.146545,0.952514,0.371123,0.528552,0.745001,0.364565,1.01051,0.0200001,0.957999,0.476094,0.0200001,0.78775,-0.343567,0.4682,-0.209197,-1.09765,0.0199999,0.882591,-0.615694,0.0199999,-0.147116,-0.146545,-0.912514,0.371123,0.528552,-0.705001,0.78775,-0.343567,-0.4282]
  "morphTargets" : []
  "normals" : [-0.880306,-0.47438,0,0.462844,0.88641,0,-0.271249,-0.962493,0,-0.965972,0.258553,0,0.184973,0.982727,0,0.685232,0.728294,0,0.798334,-0.202094,-0.567248,0.798334,-0.202094,0.567248,0.218329,-0.76101,0.610859,0.261696,0.636799,0.725242,0.218329,-0.76101,-0.610859,0.261696,0.636799,-0.725242]
  "colors" : []
  "uvs" : [[0.256514,1,0.228616,0.038417,0,0.594628,0.666692,0.948754,1,0.302325,0.746501,0,0.357698,0.026725,1,0,1,1,0,1]]
  "faces" : [42,0,8,7,0,0,1,2,0,1,2,42,0,1,4,0,0,3,4,0,3,4,42,4,5,6,0,4,5,6,4,5,6,42,0,6,8,0,0,6,1,0,6,1,42,0,4,6,0,0,4,6,0,4,6,42,8,0,7,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,42,8,11,0,0,1,6,0,1,7,0,42,4,1,0,0,4,3,0,4,3,0,42,11,5,4,0,6,5,4,7,5,4,42,11,4,0,0,6,4,0,7,4,0,42,2,1,0,0,7,8,9,8,3,0,42,1,3,2,0,7,8,9,3,9,8,42,3,4,1,0,7,8,9,9,4,3,42,5,4,3,0,7,8,9,5,4,9,42,5,6,3,0,7,8,9,5,6,9,42,3,2,6,0,7,8,9,9,8,6,42,0,7,2,0,7,8,9,0,2,8,42,6,2,7,0,7,8,9,6,8,2,42,8,7,6,0,7,8,9,1,2,6,42,5,6,8,0,7,8,9,5,6,1,42,1,9,0,0,8,7,9,3,10,0,42,10,1,9,0,8,7,9,11,3,10,42,4,10,1,0,8,7,9,4,11,3,42,4,5,10,0,8,7,9,4,5,11,42,11,5,10,0,8,7,9,7,5,11,42,9,10,11,0,8,7,9,10,11,7,42,7,0,9,0,8,7,9,2,0,10,42,9,11,7,0,8,7,9,10,7,2,42,7,8,11,0,8,7,9,2,1,7,42,11,5,8,0,8,7,9,7,5,1]
  "bones" : []
  "skinIndices" : []
  "skinWeights" : []
  "animations" : []


initThreeJS = ->
  div = $('#canvas-scene')


  window.scene = new THREE.Scene()
  window.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, div.width()/div.height(), 0.1, 1000)
  camera.position.y = 2.5
  camera.position.x = 1.5

  window.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer()

  renderer.setClearColor( '#F6FAFC' );
  renderer.setSize(div.width(), div.height())
  div.append(renderer.domElement)

  camera.position.z = 10

  loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true)
  parsed = loader.parse(kristal_json)
  kristal = new THREE.Mesh( parsed.geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xF5FCFE, ambient: 0xF1F9FC, emissive: 0xDDEDF7} ) )
  kristal.position.set(0,2,-1)
  kristal.scale.set(4,4,4)
  scene.add(kristal)


  window.light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
  light1.position.set(-9.5, 7, 7)
  scene.add light1

  render = ->
    requestAnimationFrame render

    if kristal
      kristal.rotation.y += 0.01

    renderer.render scene, camera

  render()


$ ->
  initThreeJS()
```

**P.S.**
Here is jsbin code of this http://jsbin.com/koxicuqavejo/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your material to THREE.DoubleSide

`krystal.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;`

Comment: That might work but it is not the solution. The problem is elsewhere. Double sided makes the rendering slower.

Comment: @gaitat I don't know becuase I just found this more detailed answer ;D http://stackoverflow.com/a/23641906/239036

Comment: i should have clarified better. if the model is convex and watertight closed then you should not need to specify double-sided material to view all the faces. In the example you mention the model is concave and so to see all the faces from all around you do need to specify a double-sided material.

Comment: @gaitat is correct. This answer is not the root of the problem. You are using CanvasRenderer, LambertMaterial without any lights in the scene, and your model appears to have interior faces. You need to investigate further.